# sharing data beetwin scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

## **short version**:

im building an angular app that have at least 5 scopes
i want to share data between them and im looking for the best way to do so
instead of going to $parent.$parent......

## **long version**:

i have a controller that holds multiple directives (each directive holds new $scope), from  the controller code im reaching my variables in the view with ng-modal ,but if i want that all my variables will be reachable from the right controller i need to reach the $parent.$parent.$parent scope

***im sure there is a better way.
thanks!***

Comment: Use a service to share the data.

Comment: Aggreed With @Gustav , services are best and easy to manage .

Comment: Do you mean sharing data between controllers, right?

Comment: read about [$emit & $broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) if you know, try [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Comment: @Maher no i mean $scopes.

Comment: @Oliver.t, Sorry, could you please post sample codes? Do you want to access controller scope from directive?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all the data in `services`
sample:

```
angular.
module('myServiceModule', []).
 factory('notify', [function () {
   var data = {};
   return : {
     getData : function(){ return data;}
   },
   setData : function(item){
    data = item
   }
 }]).
controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'notify', function($scope, notify) {
   $scope.someData = notify.getData();
   $scope.doSomething = function(someObj){
     notify.setData(someObj)
   }
 }]);
```

[Angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Comment: ok, but if my data will be stored in a controller ill still have to reach that controller within a scope and ill still have to reach $parent.$parent.$parent

Comment: after sorting you can update the data in the service or create a new variable from the sorted data and have to work with her.

Answer (score 0):

shared data between controllers can be put on the $rootScope which is available to all the controllers. You can directly inject $rootScope and set things on it.

However for persistence across controllers you must use services or factories.

Comment: i want to share data betwin scopes, and from what i have read putting variable in $rootScope is not the best way to solve it. thanks!